# Unable to parse remote response: Misconfigured -- Unsupported OS/browser/version/device

Tags: saucelabs, tedgebrowser, selenium-java

I wanted to run my scripts in Saucelabs by launching Edge driver but when the scripts is triggered getting an error as " Unable to parse remote response: Misconfigured -- Unsupported OS/browser/version/device combo: OS: 'Windows 10', Browser: 'edgedriver', Version: 'latest', Device: 'unspecified', Screen Resolution: '1600x1200' ".
can someone please share the edge browser capabilities to launch Edge browser in Saucelabs using Selenium Java

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("browserName","EdgeDriver");
capabilities.setCapability("platform", "Windows 10");
capabilities.setCapability("version", "88.0.4324.27");
if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("EdgeDriver")) {

//System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", 
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/LIB" + "/msedgedriver.exe");
```

//           EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions ();
//           driver = new EdgeDriver(options);

System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",
System.getProperty("user.dir")

- "/LIB" + "/msedgedriver.exe");
  driver = new EdgeDriver();
  }

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have followed as in the link and it’s working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Platform Configurator on Sauce Labs: https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator

Should now be available in the UI as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).